# Switching between Handlebar Templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm looking at the best way to switch between different Templates using Handlebars.js. I have two different cases, so using a VERY SIMPLE example

**CASE 1**

```
<script id="template-1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <div>{{Name}}</div>
</script>
```

**CASE 2**

```
<script id="template-2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <div>{{Time}}</div>
   <div>{{Place}}</div>
</script>
```

**RESULT EXAMPLE**

```
Bob

4:20
San Francisco

Tony

5:30
Seattle
```

I looked at using Partials, but not sure if that would work. Is there a best practice for doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using the {{#if}} helper. Basically I added a boolean value to my data that gets evaluated and picks the correct section to populate.